# How to get progress from copying .zip files

Tags: python

I need to copy zip files and want to get the progress printed. I have everything set so that it starts copying the file and outputs progress. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be stopping at any point. The output goes well beyond 100% and I end up killing the program.

Here is my code:

```
def copyfileobjprogress(fsrc, fdst, callback, length=16 * 1024):
    copied = 0
    MAX = os.path.getsize(default_folder)
    print(MAX)
    while True:
        with open(fsrc, 'rb') as s:
            with open(fdst, 'wb') as d:
                buf = s.read(length)
                if not buf:
                    break

                d.write(buf)
                copied += len(buf)
                callback(copied, MAX)


def percentage(copied, MAX):
    print(copied / MAX *100)
```

The first does the copying and the seconds prints the output.

Comment: Please follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) better and explain the error more. Show us a small example file that causes the error, as well as how your function is called. Include a minimal callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you execute copied again and again inside `while True` loop. What you actually do is repeating endlessly following block of code:

```
with open(fsrc, 'rb') as s:
        with open(fdst, 'wb') as d:
            buf = s.read(length)
            if not buf:
                break

            d.write(buf)
            copied += len(buf)
            callback(copied, MAX)
```

Which means you open 2 files, read the input content from beginning, so read result stored in `buf` is not empty, so you don't break loop, then write to output file and again open 2 files, read inputs' content ....

What you could try instead is first open files, then read and write in loop i.e.

```
   with open(fsrc, 'rb') as s:
        with open(fdst, 'wb') as d:
            while True:
                 ...
```

Comment: Ah, true! Stupid mistake on my part. 
Thank you very much for the aid!